# Log used options in .catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, callback

I have a helper which exports the the function `myLimitedRq: function (u, a, cb1, cb2)` this function uses a rate limiter to limit api requests. Inside the limiter the options for the request promise are set. If the request was succesful cb1 is called and returns the data. If not cb2 is called and returns the error. What I want is to return the error AND the used options for the request.

```
rp(options).then(function (res) {
            return cb1(res);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return cb2(err);
        });
```

How can I return the error and the options used in "options"?

Comment: You should be able to return a different result using the `cb2` callback. Would something like this work: `return cb2(err, options)` or `return cb2({error: err, options: options})`?

Comment: Alternatively you could add the logging logic in the `.catch` segment for a more universal error logging

Comment: @VasilDininski the first thing worked. So simple. Thank you!